# Nested Query for Attachment

Tags: query, nested

I need to retieve the Manager Parent Task id in Attachment query. Can we query the grantParent Id in the same query , below query is giving me id of employee and manger but I need task id also which is parent of Manager__c

```
SELECT ParentId, 
    TYPEOF Parent
        WHEN Employee__c THEN MangerId__c 
    END 
    FROM Attachment
    WHERE Parent.Type = 'Employee__c'
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  I'm a bit confused, what exactly is your schema here?  A diagram (use [edit] would hellp

Comment: I need Id's in single query . The above will fetch me Id of employee and attachment and Manager but I need Id of Manager Parent as well that is case . Grandparent id I need .

Comment: For understanding attachment has a parent contact and contact has parent account and account has parent case . I want ids of all 4 object in single query.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse parent fields in the TYPEOF expression

Let's look at a standard example

```
User
 |    (lookup via ManagerId, relationship name = Manager)
User 
 |
Account (lookup via OwnerId, relationship name = Owner)
 |
Contact  (lookup via AccountId, relationship name = Account)
 |
Attachment (via ParentId) 

SELECT ParentId,
  TYPEOF Parent
    WHEN Contact THEN Id, AccountId, Account.OwnerId,
                      Account.Owner.ManagerId, 
                      Account.Owner.Manager.Name
  END
  FROM Attachment
WHERE Parent.Type = 'Contact'
```

gets you the parent (and grandXXParent) ids of this hierarchy plus the Account Owner's manager's Name